# How to use our own Hard Disk as a database of Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, server, nosql, web-development-server

Does anyone knows how we can create our own database in mongodb which will be available to anyone in this world ? As i have created database locally and used mongodb atlas but it charges me. As i want to use it for development , which is only accessible to my team members ?

Comment: "_mongodb atlas but it charges me_" - Atlas, and other cloud offerings, have free tier plans that may be appropriate depending on the point in the development cycle that your project is in

Answer (score 1):

Deploy a normal stand-alone MongoDB instance.

See [Install MongoDB Community Edition](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/administration/install-community/)

In order to make the database accessible from remote host, use this setting in configuration file:

```
net:
  bindIpAll: true
```

And of course, enable authorization, e.g. [Use SCRAM to Authenticate Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/)

Just a note, you ask "create a database in MongoDB which will be available to anyone in this world" - you must not offer such database as a public cloud service where end-users have to pay for (i.e. like the MongoDB Atlas service). This is not permitted with the MongoDB Community Edition according to the license conditions.